# SubSonic 3 isn't generating Foreign Key tables as a property

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

Basically, I'm having the same problem as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956191/subsonic-isnt-generating-mysql-foreign-key-tables/2900948#2900948), but in SubSonic 3.0. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to change the provider in SubSonic 3.0.

Is this something I need to change in the MySQL.ttinclude, Settings.ttinclude or one of the T4 templates? Or does it go in config somewhere?

Thoughts? Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950692/subsonic-foreign-key-returning-collection) that says that it's as designed. I can't imagine why. I changed the Classes.tt file to generate a single mapping. The relevant code is below. However, this relies on the fact that all my PKs are named Id, but you should be able to get the idea.

Before the IQueryable<> generation part:

```
if (fk.ThisColumn == "Id")
{ 
   //This is where the standard IQueryable goes
} else {
   //This is what I added
   public <#= fk.OtherTable #> <#= fk.OtherTable #>
   {
      get 
      {
         var db=new <#=Namespace #>.<#=DatabaseName#>DB();
         return from items in db.<#=fk.OtherQueryable #>
                where items.<#=fk.OtherColumn#> == _<#=fk.ThisColumn#>
                select items;
      }
   }
}
```

Hopefully that helps. I'm trying to figure out now to do many to many tables now :/

Answer (score 0):

I am using Subsonic 2.2 and I am facing the same issue, but this worked on my problem: Apart from original provider `MySqlDataProvider`, there is an extended version: `MySqlInnoDBDataProvider`

So in your web.config, making sure the provider is choosn:

```
  <add name="MyProvider" 
       type="SubSonic.MySqlInnoDBDataProvider, SubSonic" 
       connectionStringName="WriteConnectionString" 
       generatedNamespace="AttendAnywhere.Data" 
       generateLazyLoads="true" 
       extractClassNameFromSPName="true" />
```