# Subsonic foreign key returning collection?

Tags: c#, subsonic

I'm just writing my first "Hello World" program using Subsonic, for which I've thrown together a simple little Customer/Invoice/InvoiceItem/Product database.

The connection was successfully made to the DB, and it generated all the right `ActiveRecord` classes.  But for some reason, the `Invoice` class has a property called `Customers`, which returns a collection of `Customer` objects, even though the `Invoice` table has a `CustomerID` field which has a foreign key to the `Customer` table.  I would have expected a `Customer` property returning a single `Customer` object.

Same thing is happening for all of my FKs.  I must be doing something wrong - but what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected behavior.  The first (and only) item in the Invoice.Customers collection will be the foreign key related Customer object.

Comment: Why is that expected behavior?  I'm coming from the built in Linq-To-SQL O/R Designer, and that generate relationships along the lines I've describedas "expected behavior".  You have to admit that makes more logical sense, no?  It's obvious there was some technical issue here that forced a rather kludgy workaround - but why?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is how it was implemented in SubSonic 3.  SubSonic 2 would generate an Invoice.Customer field as you mentioned.  However, you can add this field yourself in the T4 templates.